# How to call addItems iteratively within a for loop when when calling app.buildCarousel()

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to create multiple items within a Carousel based on a result set. I am using the for loop to parse the result set. But I don't know how to add an item within the for loop.

Sample:

```
app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
.addSimpleResponse("Alright. Here are the result")
.addSuggestions(['Basic Card', 'List', 'Carousel', 'Suggestions']),
app.buildCarousel()
videos.forEach(function(item){
  .addItems(app.BuildOptionItem('${item.id.videoId}',['1', 'First one'])
                .setTitle(item.snippet.title)
                .setDescription(item.snippet.description)
                .setImage(item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url, 'image'))

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this.
const carousel = app.buildCarousel()

videos.forEach(function(item){
    carousel.addItems(app.BuildOptionItem('${item.id.videoId}',['1', 'First one'])
            .setTitle(item.snippet.title)
            .setDescription(item.snippet.description)
            .setImage(item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url, 'image'))

});

app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
.addSimpleResponse("Alright. Here are the result")
.addSuggestions(['Basic Card', 'List', 'Carousel', 'Suggestions']),
carousel
);
```